# Type of reaction between metal and salt

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, ionic-compounds

What type of reaction is the following?

$\ce{ 10Na(l) + 2KNO3 (s) -> K2O(s) + 5Na2O(s) + N2 (g)}$

So far my best guess has been that it's a double replacement reactions with evolution of gas. Is this correct or am I totally lost?

Edit: It's not a double replacement reactions with evolution of gas (don't know why I thought it was), but what is it then?

Comment: K2O won't be gaseous. I rewrote reaction to be readable but check your details.

Comment: My bad. K2O should be solid...

Comment: Now that's funny, if I added proper redox tag I would basically answer via tagging! So, yes it's redox, you could maybe call it also decomposition...

Comment: So what you are saying is that, it's a decomposition reaction? But couldn't you also say that a addition reaction is happening? Some of the oxygen has been separated from the Kaliumnitrate Binds with two of the Sodium to form Sodium Oxide?

Comment: Seems you're not getting it, there are redox reactions and the rest and no I think it shouldn't be called decomposition as two thing react and definitely not addition. Also I think that trying to put it into other categories than redox is waste of time.

Comment: Reactions don't really have types, even though some textbooks might try to convince you otherwise.